# Vacuum energy and supersymmetry

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, supersymmetry, anthropic-principle

Let us assume that dark energy is the energy of the vacuum.

The density of this vacuum energy has been measured to be about $10^{-26}$ $kg/m^3$.
Using the Compton wavelength formula, $\lambda=h/mc$, this implies that the vacuum energy scale is only about $10^{-3}eV$.

Is supersymmetry the only known effect that can cause the vacuum energy to be so small?

As I understand it we know that supersymmetry is broken as we haven't found any superpartner particles with the same masses as the known particles of the standard model.

Do the current results from the LHC already put some lower bound on the energy scale of supersymmetry breaking? If so what does this energy scale imply for the energy scale of the vacuum? I would have thought that it would imply a higher vacuum energy scale than $10^{-3}eV$.

Comment: Why (and *how*) are you using the Compton wavelength formula on an energy density of the vacuum, and why do you think supersymmetry has something to do with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Standard Model coupled to GR as an effective theory, the cosmological constant is predicted to be $m_{Pl}^4$ i.e. $10^{123}$ times the correct value (you mentioned the correct value).

SUSY improves this situation by cancellations between superpartners (fermions contribute the same to the C.C. as their bosonic partners but with the opposite sign if SUSY is unbroken). But because the cancellation gets inaccurate if the superpartners' masses diverge (by the SUSY breaking) and because the experimental lower bound on the superpartner masses is around $100\,{\rm GeV}$ (in most models allowed by the LHC, the gluino is already heavier than $1\,{\rm TeV}$ etc. and allowed models with any superpartners below this value have been reduced although the stop around 600 GeV is still OK etc.), it seems that $m_{SUSY}^4$ is still the minimum "generic" prediction by SUSY. It's better than $m_{Pl}^4$ but it is still 60 orders of magnitude too high. In some sense, the problem is numerically improved but conceptually worsened because with SUGRA, one gets more certain that this is the right order-of-magnitude estimate.

One indeed needs some cancellation up to $(1\,{\rm meV})^4$, as you mentioned, but no one has presented a persuasive (at least for most people) explanation why should all the other, larger contributions cancel or be unphysical. The millielectronvolt scale you mentioned is comparable to the mass of the neutrinos – the lightest massive particles in Nature – as well as to $m_{EW}^2/m_{Pl}$ "seesaw scale" and there are other hints that it could have something to do with other quantities we know in Nature and papers with some heuristic arguments exist but none of them makes a full sense yet.

So I think it's right to say that people don't know and the anthropic explanation that allows lots, over $10^{60}$, values of the cosmological constant, and a viable small value is chosen because it admits life, is the "existing proposal" favored by the largest number of experts.

I personally think that some no-scale SUSY with some extra special mechanism or realization will actually be shown to give the better cancellation and the simple cancellation reducing the problem from 120 to 60 orders of magnitude will be seen as the first step out of two to solve the problem. 15 years ago, it was fashionable to say that the cosmological constant problem is surely the biggest problem whose solution would clarify almost everything else. People aren't saying this statement so often today.

So if you were asking whether the introduction of SUSY has been enough to solve the cosmological constant problem (why the constant is so tiny), the answer is "no, at most 1/2 of the problem". ;)

Comment: I've heard lots of explanations of this idea, but this one made a lot of sense!

Answer (score -1):

the big bang created the real space vacum when the "explotion" created a "super Situation" the expantion is faster then light and will create a vacum "inside" and push the event horrizon away and back in the same action